# How can I prevent myself from getting logged out automatically in a multi-user setup?

Tags: kde, users

I am using my machine with multiple accounts logged in at the same time. I am using KDM desktop manager and KDE desktop. Ever since I upgraded to Karmic, when using one user the second user, who is active on another virtual terminal, gets logged out automatically. I have looked through the logs and can't find anything that would cause this.

What should I be looking into to figure it out? Is there some sort of feature that was turned on through the upgrades? (the machine has been through many releases..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I lived with this for a while and ended up upgrading Ubuntu to a newer version and it went away. So not sure what it was but probably a bug somewhere..

Answer (score 4):

You can check that you have enough **TTY**'s:

Open a terminal and do:

```
grep tty /etc/default/console-setup
```

It should show (check the last number, it should say 6):

```
ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
```

**If not**, edit the /etc/default/console-setup file by typing:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/console-setup
```

And look for ACTIVE_CONSOLES, and make the line look this:

```
ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
```

Comment: there are enough ttys.